# Big O notation of recursive functions

Tags: time, big-o, complexity-theory, notation

I have been practicing big O notation and I seem to understand it except for when it comes to recursive functions. I can deal with the simple ones (like when it is `O(n)` or `O(1)` but anything else I usually just get lost. 
Below are three that are practice problems, I would really appreciate if someone explained the process on how they find the answer.

```
  public static int method2(int n)
  {
    if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (n == 1)
      return 2;
    else
      return method2(n - 1) * (2 * n);
  }


  public static void method3(int n)
  {
    if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (n == 1)
      System.out.print("1");
    else {
      method3(n - 1);
      System.out.print(", " + n);
    }
  }


  public static void method4(int n)
  {
    if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (n==1) System.out.print(1);
    else if (n==2) System.out.print("1 1");
    else {
        System.out.print((n+1)/2+ " ");
        method4(n-2);
        System.out.print(" "+(n+1)/2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just think about how the problem shrinks with each recursive call.  For example, if it shrinks linearly, and there is only a single call per recursion, it will be O(n).  If each call creates two new calls and they both shrink linearly, it will be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

This examples are quite straightforward.

In `method2`, you start with `n`, and go down by `1` until it comes to `1`. so you will have `n` calls of `method2` and that is `O(n)`.

`method3` is same as `method2`, just different operation. You call `method3` until its 1 by decreasing `n` by `1`.

In `method4` you decrease `n` by `2`, until its `1` or `2`, so you will do `n/2` steps, which is still O(n).

This are not quite the best examples to understand the speed of recursive functions. You need to play around with examples that have more than one option for recursion.

All this options can be transform to for loops with same complexity, so try to think in that way if it can help you.